# Undo overflow: hidden in child element

Tags: css, overflow

I have a simple set up, with a sticky footer. It works fine in a jsbin sandbox, but in the template I am using one of the parent (inner-wrapper in the example) has `overflow: hidden` css property, what messes up the sticky footer. Is it a way to wrap the `main-container` with a div and override the `inner-wrapper`'s overflow property? I have tried to add `overflow: visible` to the div `undo-overflow`.

Here is the desired result: https://jsbin.com/merikujosa/4/edit?html,css,output or just simple remove the .inner-wrapper's overflow property.

```css
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.inner-wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.undo-overflow {
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-container{ max-width:600px;  margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa;
}
.main-content{
  
}

.main-footer{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; bottom:0; border-color:red;}
```

```html
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="undo-overflow">
      <main class="main-container">
        <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
        <div class="main-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel condimentum nisl, vel rutrum arcu. Aliquam venenatis nulla ac mi ornare fermentum. Nunc sagittis lobortis turpis, elementum maximus libero pharetra in. Etiam quis nisi vel nisi gravida suscipit sed id eros. Sed nec metus eget arcu dictum interdum. Praesent quis sollicitudin nisl. Maecenas ex sapien, feugiat vitae lectus a, faucibus dignissim lectus. Curabitur eros erat, convallis et lorem vel, faucibus elementum mi. Fusce porttitor ligula id erat mattis gravida. Aenean pharetra a lacus eget volutpat. Proin scelerisque sagittis condimentum. Donec vitae ex nunc. Aliquam dignissim tempor mollis.

      Aliquam nec pulvinar arcu, sed sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse gravida porta elit, id commodo nulla aliquam at. Duis in est consequat, finibus diam vitae, vulputate mauris. Sed blandit tortor ipsum, sed luctus lectus elementum eget. Quisque vel placerat mi, vel lobortis libero. Duis malesuada fermentum dolor, id vehicula ligula imperdiet quis. Quisque ipsum odio, ornare quis tempus in, varius eget nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras egestas fringilla efficitur. Vestibulum vitae vestibulum sem. Nunc vel libero vel nunc vestibulum scelerisque at interdum metus. Aliquam leo nulla, varius in urna non, pellentesque blandit nisl. Nulla laoreet leo justo, nec scelerisque leo tempus id.

      Nulla quis fringilla turpis. Nunc vitae justo est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc et justo vel erat porta gravida. Integer rutrum malesuada nulla, sit amet ultricies velit fermentum vel. Nulla at sapien in purus facilisis maximus. Quisque ultrices, elit in elementum iaculis, tellus diam tincidunt est, sed auctor magna ante et nulla. Praesent eu leo consectetur, blandit justo rhoncus, venenatis tellus. Vivamus viverra neque hendrerit ipsum interdum iaculis. Aenean vulputate nunc vel justo congue, et lacinia sapien tempor. Suspendisse non magna velit. Morbi tempus mi id ex varius placerat. Pellentesque eleifend venenatis ante non aliquam. Quisque vel aliquet eros. Curabitur sodales, tellus sit amet placerat dapibus, ligula felis facilisis est, eu scelerisque augue leo in massa.

      Duis scelerisque imperdiet sem nec ornare. Maecenas varius, lorem non iaculis suscipit, lacus neque cursus lacus, vitae pretium dolor lectus eget nisl. Quisque finibus porta nibh in accumsan. Donec semper ante nec massa convallis vulputate. Sed blandit vel libero rutrum vestibulum. Aenean eget lacus nec arcu consequat hendrerit nec id velit. Aenean maximus ipsum vel euismod auctor. Aliquam enim libero, lobortis at convallis quis, malesuada eu dui. Nunc eget volutpat odio, sed hendrerit felis.

      Quisque convallis aliquet bibendum. Mauris malesuada urna a interdum venenatis. Nunc auctor varius luctus. Vivamus ac ultricies sapien, in suscipit dui. Duis tristique velit ut posuere tincidunt. Cras non laoreet augue, eu bibendum elit. Quisque sed scelerisque lorem, at fringilla orci.

      </div>
        <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
      </main>
      <br><br><br><br>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you be more specific (or illustrate what you see and what you want to achieve) because in your snippet and jsbin everything looks fine.  I don't even understand what are you trying to do or what the `overflow: hidden;` is suppose to hide.

Comment: I have updated the jsbin. There you can see the the desired result. (Footer should be sticky to the bottom, but if .inner-wrapper has `overflow: hidden` then it does not work)

Comment: Why do you wanna add an `overflow: hidden` if it works perfectly without it ?

Comment: I do not want to add, but in the template I use it comes with it. The content is dynamic inside the inner wrapper and on some other pages uses the overflow: hidden, but the one in my example does not need it.

Comment: Then can't you simply remove the class `.inner-wrapper` or the `overflow-hidden` line in the CSS file ? If you can't do any of these, then I suggest you to add `.inner-wrapper{overflow: visible;}` after the original code to *overwrite* the previous unwanted styling.

Comment: I can not remove it, because it is used on other pages. It is part of the site's frame. The inner content of the site is dynamic (different pages). Some of those pages need that css rule, but the page I am working on does not.